# NserviceBus change default db schema for table to create

Tags: nservicebus

I am wondering if this is possible to change default schema for tables created by NSB.
I tried add this key:

```
<add key="NServiceBus/Persistence/NHibernate/default_schema" value="other"/>
```

but this seems to be used for setting schema only for reading from, not as default schema used with creating tables. Is there any way to set it up?

Comment: I've raised an issue about this, see https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.NHibernate/issues/30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is a bug that I'm fixing as part of https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.NHibernate/pull/28

This fix will be going out very soon.
I'm sorry for the inconvenience, but for now the only workaround is to generate the TSQL from whatever is currently created and then manually update the schema and redo the tables.

Comment: Can you tell me when exactly you think it might be fixed ?

Comment: In the next minor release, which is due soon